# How to get dates from database and store them into array in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, date

I have been working on Leave module on a project. I want to calculate the leave days of an employee excluding national holidays and weekends.
So, i have a table named attendance having field AttDate where date have been stored when employee are being present.
i just want to know how can i import database date values to variable datesOfWorker in array form as being predefined in function.

[here is the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947134/how-to-get-days-absent-from-working-days-from-given-date-range/11002672#11002672)

Comment: Please share the code or something you had done so far.

Comment: please follow the hyperlink

Comment: You want an sql query to fetch data or how to format the date as in the function?

Comment: basically i know the sql query but how can i put that sql query into array form as mentioned in the function.

Comment: i want to know how can i pass my database AttDate values to the WorkingDatesOf Worker in the function.

Comment: It will all depend on the structure of your Table. Could you at the least show us a Screen-Shot of your Table. That would help.

Comment: [link](http://s32.postimg.org/a91eiy0jp/Capture.jpg) here is the snapshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres  what I'd suggest you try:

```
    <?php
        // DEFINE SOME DATABASE CONNECTION DATA... COULD BE DONE IN A SEPARATE FILE
        defined("HOST")         or define("HOST",           "localhost");
        defined("DBASE")        or define("DBASE",          "mydb");
        defined("USER")         or define("USER",           "root");        //<== YOUR USERNAME
        defined("PASS")         or define("PASS",           "root");        //<== YOUR PASSWORD

        function getDBH(){
            try {
                $dbHandle = new \PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='. DBASE,USER,PASS);
                $dbHandle->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                return $dbHandle;
            }catch(\PDOException $e){
                throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        $dbh        = getDBH();
        $output     = "";
        $sql        = "SELECT ATT.AttDate FROM `attendance` ATT";
        $query      = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        $results    = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $arrDates   = array();

        foreach($results as $intKey=>$objAttDate){
            $arrDates[] = $objAttDate->AttDate;
        }

        // THE ARRAY YOU ARE LOOKING FOR IS $arrDates...

        var_dump($arrDates);
```

Comment: Thanks @Poiz this is what i was looking for.
can we make it dynamic as many of the employee are marking their attendance their can we dynamically get leave details of any employee present

Comment: @Aman Singh  Sure making it dynamic is a matter of fetching and using the att_id within the SQL. If you still wish the Post above revisited to reflect that too, just drop you comment...  Cheers...

Comment: yes i wish to get details of specific employee that should be dynamically.